# Pagina web dinámica

Tags: javascript, php, html5, menu

Buenos días tardes y/o noches.

Estoy intentando hacer mi pagina web de forma dinámica, que llame contenido sin necesidad de recargar la pagina, puesto que es una pagina de una sola vista y no múltiples (o esa es la idea). El enlace es este -> [Gabriel Yturrino](https://gabrielyturrino.com/web).

Lo intente con Js utilizando el siguiente código:

```
function abrirUrl(url, container) {

    $.get(url, {}, function (data) {

        $("#" + container).html(data);

    });

}
```

Pero no lograba que llamara el contenido. Luego vi en un video que con `PHP` podría realizarlo, y si funciona, pero el detalle es que para cargar la nueva información, se recarga toda la pagina como si hubieras ingresado nuevamente.

El código `PHP` es este:

```
<?php

//Logica para capturar la pagina que deseas abrir
    $pagina = isset($_GET['p']) ? strtolower($_GET['p']) : 'inicio';

//Frangmento de la primera parte del HTML
    require_once 'includes/header.php';

//Ubica la pagina a solicitar. Caso contrario rediriege a la pagina 404
    @require_once 'pages/' . $pagina . '.php';

//Ultima parte del cuerpo del HTML

    require_once 'includes/foot.php'

?>
```

Este es el código del menú:

```
<nav class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="<?php echo $pagina == 'inicio' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                                <a href="?p=inicio" class="opciones"><i class="icon-persona"></i><span>Sobre mí</span>
                            </a></li>
                            <li class="<?php echo $pagina == 'experiencia' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                                <a href="?p=experiencia" class="opciones"><i class="icon-laboral"></i><span>Experiencia Laboral</span>
                            </a></li>
                            <li class="<?php echo $pagina == 'portfolio' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                                <a href="?p=portfolio" class="opciones"><i class="icon-portafolio"></i><span>Portafolio</span>
                            </a></li>
                            <li class="<?php echo $pagina == 'estudios' ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                                <a href="?p=estudios" class="opciones"><i class="icon-estudios"></i><span>Estudios Realizados</span>
                            </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

Comment: debes crear un <div> u otro elemento con nombre por medio del cual puedas hacer el llamado solo a ese <div>, paralelamente tu div debe ser igual que el de la pagina original para no perder formatos.

Comment: Claro, cuando use Js, lo hice como me indicas... teniendo un div identificado por una clase (la misma del código js) donde se colocara la la info llamada pero simplemente nunca la llamaba.

Comment: El llamado se hace manualmente a través de algún botón o link o evento o alguna rutina con tiempo programado, recuerde que la página se enviá al cliente según la petición que el hace al servidor, el html es estático y se ejecuta en la maquina cliente.

Comment: El llamado de hace manualmente, al hacer clic en el enlace del menú

Comment: Y no has pensado hacerla en angular o react?

Comment: Perdón por la intromisión, pero veo que tu página es presencial, por lo tanto esperas que google la indexe y la encuentren facilmente, cosa que usando javascript para cargar los contenidos vas a dificultar de mala manera.  Lo mejor para este tipo de páginas, si te importa el SEO, es usar urls amigables para cada contenido que quieras aportar, y dejar el javascript para otro tipo de webs. Es mi opinión simplemente, no quiero ofender a nadie, suerte!

Comment: Google indexa bien las `SPA`.  Solo encargate de poner las `meta tags` y tabaja bien el diseño `responsive`

Comment: @masterguru no hay problema, igualmente, gracias por la observación!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de la implementación de un colega.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn1').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "hola.php",
            success: function(response) {
                $('#div-results').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Esta función se debe llamar mediante un botón llamado `btn1`

`<a class="btn btn-success" id="btn1">Ver el archivo que contiene hola</a>`

dentro de la página estara el div a modificar

```
<div id="div-results"></div>
```

y por otro lado tu archivo php es el que hará la interacción con el servidor

```php
<?php
echo '<p>ESTE ES EL ARCHIVO PHP QUE CONTIENE EL HOLA</p>';
?>
```

te dejo su [enlace](https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/ajax-link/)

Comment: Esta es una respuesta muy valida!  Recuerda utilizar La `CDN` de JQuery

Comment: Voy a probar implementándola gracias por la guía!

Comment: Algo debo de estar haciendo mal por que sigue sin llamar al contenido... Estoy haciendo un descarte implementando algo totalmente simple para encontrar el error... Gracias por la respuesta igualmente!

Comment: Solucionado @rpaillao gracias por la ayuda